# Not getting correct redirect URI for Google Analytics installedapp (custom plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I am developing a custom WordPress plugin to retrieve the page views and URL of posts. According to [gaDataAuthorization](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataAuthorization), Plugin is an installed application.

And [ouath2InstalledApp](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp). Here I read it is same as [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer), having three differences.

But when I am trying to use `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` as the redirect URI, it is not working. Can anybody give me any idea?

In the developer console it alerts:

> Must have a protocol. Cannot contain URL fragments or relative paths.
>       Cannot be a public IP address. '
>
> `redirect_uri` |    *One of the redirect_uri values obtained from the
>   Google Developers Console.*     | Determines where the response is sent.
>   The value of this parameter must exactly match one of the values that
>   appear in the Credentials page in the Google Developers Console
>   (including the http or https scheme, case, and trailing slash). You
>   may choose between urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob,
>   urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto, or an http://localhost port. For more
>   details, see Choosing a redirect URI.

Comment: "not working". share what happens. post any error messages / logging of errors.

Comment: add that to your question

Comment: @Jonathon updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture below shows where you need to choose "other". The Hello analytics app does not specify it.

That will create your [installedApp](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp) (the WordPress plugin is treated as installedApp). Now you do not need to specify redirect URI on your console.

Another question of mine will guide you better on your further steps. It is *[How to use refresh token to get authorized in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870439/how-to-use-refresh-token-to-get-authorized-in-background-and-getting-access-toke)*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems Google allows you to use any URI as a redirect URI. On the other hand, it seems other software libraries you are using accept only `http://` or `https://`.

Comment: I am using wamp on windows .

Comment: 'Must have a protocol. Cannot contain URL fragments or relative paths.
Cannot be a public IP address. ' this is the guidelines for redirect URI and  document suggests 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto, or an http://localhost port' but when I use any of the first two, I get error alerting  the guidelines .